# Proving the boundary of B is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was to prove the boundary of a set is closed.

In this context, $B$ is a subset in a topological space $X$

I have started by defining $\partial B = \bar{B} \cap (X\setminus B^\circ)$ so I can then say $\partial B$ must be closed as it is the intersection of two closed sets, I just wondered if there was any further evidence I could give for the sets that are intersected being closed as it seems clear intuitively but I'm otherwise struggling

Comment: The intersection of closed sets is always closed. This follows from the axioms of what it means for $X$ to be a topological space.

Comment: You don't need further evidence in order to prove that the boundary of any $B$ is closed.

Comment: Same idea: write $\partial B = \overline{B}\cap \overline{B^\complement}$, also an intersection of closed sets. (unions of open sets are open so intersections of closed sets are closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the following identity:
\begin{align*}
X = \text{int}(B)\cup\partial B\cup\text{ext}(B)
\end{align*}

where $\text{int}(B)$ denotes the interior of $B$, $\partial B$ denotes the boundary of $B$ and $\text{ext}(B)$ is the exterior of $B$.

More precisely, $x\in\text{int}(B)$ iff there exists an open set $O$ such that $x\in O\subset B$.

We also say that $x\in\text{ext}(B)$ iff there exists an open set $O$ such that $x\in O$ and $O\cap B = \varnothing$.

We say that $x\in X$ is a boundary point of $B$ iff it is neither an interior point nor an exterior point.

Once $\text{int}(B)$, $\partial B$ and $\text{ext}(B)$ are pairwise disjoint, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(\partial B)^{c} = \text{int}(B)\cup\text{ext}(B)
\end{align*}
which is open. Hence $\partial B$ is closed, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !